# Wanted: IE9 table cell ghost, alive and without JS

Tags: datatable, internet-explorer-9, cell

The IE9 layout engine has issues with tables. Whitespace seems at the root of it.

If you've seen the infamous ghost cell you know what I'm talking about, if you haven't, consider yourself lucky and don't worry about it.

Anyways, I'd really like an **HTML only** sample to test "fixes" on.

I know I've seen it before in odd circumstances several layout tables deep, but I can no longer get the ghost cell to come up when I need it to.

**What I need is a consistent ghost cell without invoking JS.**

I've found several JS related ones, and there are plenty discussion on those when it comes to sorting.

This is a great sample:

http://www.ncf.ca/ncf/support/ie9_issue/index.html

Some discussions:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/28d78780-c95c-4c35-9695-237ebb912d90

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5481/bug-ghost-columns-when-generating-large-tables/p1

http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8248/datatable-in-ie-9-bug-with-large-tables/p1

Comment: What are you actually asking for?

Comment: Kinda what jornare did, but I would love it if the <script> tag could be removed completely. I'm not really asking anyone to work on this, just hope to catch the attention of someone who has a working sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to clean up the html quite well and still keep the issue. I replaced all the javascript with equivalent spaces & newlines, and could remove most of the elements attributes without affecting the ghost-cell.

It seems like IE has a buffer problem since removing single spaces or newlines in a "safe area" cause the ghost cell to disappear, while removing entire attributes does not affect the rendering.

I see that you have unclosed  tags, but I also managed to remove them altogether (replacing with spaces) without removing the ghost cell.

Result being I have a javascript-free html with ghost-cell. See result here: http://compscicon.no/ghostcell.htm

Comment: There's no way you could get it to appear without the <javascript> tag being in the page could you?

Comment: If no-one else comes along, and I doubt anyone will, I'll still award you the bounty as this gets me ever so closer to figuring out wtf is really going on.

Comment: Yes, just did it and uploaded to my server again. I'm behind a CDN so if it does not update right away it's because of cache.

Comment: Awesome thank you! You don't happen to know of a better solution than t.innerHTML = t.innerHTML.replace(RegExp('>[ \t\r\n\v\f]*<', 'g'), '><');  I'm also currently working on a JS script that scans the node tree of tables looking for whitespace to remove them, imagine it would be a little more elegant than that little bit of RegEx.

Comment: I'd clean up server-side to avoid it in the first place. Seems it only happens when you have a lot of it (say around 2000 chars).

Comment: unfortunately there is alot of it, and I can't fix this issue on the server-side, so I've taken to writing a JS function to do it... having some node removal bottlenecks. :( sigh, ohh well, thanks once again for all your help